# Error when attempting to use the "parentActivityName" attribute

Tags: android, ant, terminal, android-manifest

I know this question has been asked multiple times before but the responses to all of them are more or less the same, and it seems that answer isn't relevant to my issue.

I'm writing an app in which one activity needs to navigate back to a certain activity regardless of how it got there. This is how the activity entry in the manifest file looks:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.project.namespace.ClassName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:parentActivityName="com.project.namespace.MainActivity" >
    <!-- Meta data required for devices below 4.1 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.project.namespace.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

The package/class names have been renamed for this.

When I try to build the project (I'm using ant to build via the terminal) I get the following error:

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'parentActivityName' in package 'android'
```

From the other questions I've read, the issue is usually that SDK 16 is required for this attribute to work. I have SDKs 14-19 installed, with 14 being my minimum SDK and my target is 19. Does anyone have a clue as to why this error is still appearing? From what I've researched it should be working fine.

For the record, I've also tried reinstalling SDK 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. include android support libraries in your project
2. set your project's build target to 4.1

Comment: That was the problem! I misunderstood setting the build target for setting the minimum SDK version. I've updated my project and it built correctly.